# ContactBitMask indicates that my objects collide, but they didn't

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, physics

I was coding this game, and the game is over when the pig and fish collide. But when I play it, the pig didn't touch the fish but the game automatically overs. How do i fix that? The method related are did began and eaten etc.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

var totalTime = 0
class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
private var label : SKLabelNode?
var flyingPig:SKSpriteNode!
var water = SKSpriteNode()
var scoreLabel :SKLabelNode!

var currentGameState = gameState.atGame



struct PhysicsCategories{
    static let None :UInt32 = 0
    static let pig : UInt32 = 0b1
    static let aFish : UInt32 = 0b100
}

var timer : Timer!
var timing : Timer!
var fish = ["nemo","bluedy","lantern","balloon","Knife"]
var myTime = 0
var lives:[SKSpriteNode]!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    totalTime = 0
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    water = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "water")

    water.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2,y:self.size.height/2)

    water.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: water.size)

    water.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    water.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    self.addChild(water)

    flyingPig = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"FlyingPig")
    flyingPig.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width/2,y:self.size.height/2)
    flyingPig.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: flyingPig.size)
    flyingPig.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity=false
    flyingPig.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
    flyingPig.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.pig
    flyingPig.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.aFish
    self.addChild(flyingPig)

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx:0,dy:0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text:"Score: 0")
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:85,y:1270)
    scoreLabel.fontName = "PartyLetPlain"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 44
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(totalTime) km"
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1.25 ,target:self,selector:#selector(addFish),userInfo:nil,repeats:true)

    timing = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.5, target: self, selector: #selector(tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    addLives()
}


func addLives()
{
    lives = [SKSpriteNode()]
    for live in 1...3{
        let liveNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"FlyingPig2")
        liveNode.position = CGPoint(x:750-CGFloat(4-live)*liveNode.size.width,y:1270)
        self.addChild(liveNode)
        lives.append(liveNode)
    }
}

func addFish()
{
    fish = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: fish) as![String]

    let aFish = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: fish[0])

    let fishPosition = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue:0, highestValue:700)
    let position = CGFloat(fishPosition.nextInt())
    aFish.position=CGPoint(x:position,y:1200)

    aFish.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: aFish.size)
    aFish.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    aFish.physicsBody?.isDynamic=false
    aFish.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.aFish
    aFish.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
    aFish.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.pig
    self.addChild(aFish)



    let animationDuration:TimeInterval = 12
    var actionArray = [SKAction]()
    actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to:CGPoint(x:position,y:-800),duration:animationDuration))
    aFish.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
        }

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var body1 = SKPhysicsBody()
    var body2 = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask{
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    }
    else{
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.pig && body2.categoryBitMask==PhysicsCategories.aFish
    {
        body2.node?.removeFromParent()
        gameOver()
    }
}

enum gameState{
    case before
    case atGame
    case after
}


func gameOver(){
    self.removeAllActions()
    currentGameState=gameState.after
    let changeSceneAction = SKAction.run(changeScene)
    let waitToChangeScene = SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.1)
    let changeSceneSequence = SKAction.sequence([waitToChangeScene,changeSceneAction])
    self.run(changeSceneSequence)



}
func changeScene(){
    let newScene = GameOverScene(size:self.size)
    newScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
    let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.1)
    self.view!.presentScene(newScene,transition:transition )

}


func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

}

func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    for touch in (touches ){
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    if self.flyingPig.contains(location){
        flyingPig.position = location
        }
    }

}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in (touches ){
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if flyingPig.contains(location){
            flyingPig.position = location
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       }


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}


func tick()
{
    totalTime+=1

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.pig && body2.categoryBitMask==PhysicsCategories.aFish
```

change to this

```
let contactMask = bodyA.contact.categoryBitMask || bodyB.contact.categoryBitMask

switch contactMask
    case PhysicsCategories.pig ||  PhysicsCategories.aFish :
        // code
    default:
        break
```